# SQL MAX() Function returning All Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, greatest-n-per-group

So first I would like to preface this question by letting everyone know I am pretty new to sql and coding in general. I have a query:

```
    Select Distinct 
[t1].[Name] AS Subdivision
, [t2].[Description] AS SubStatus
, [t4].[Name] AS ConnectingSubName
, [t2].[Description] As ConnectingSubStatus
, [t5].[ActualPublicationEndDate]
, MAX([t5].[version]) as Version

From [PtcDbTracker].[dbo].[TrackDatabase] as [t0]
INNER Join [PTCDbTracker].[dbo].[Subdivision] as [t1] on [t0].   [SubdivisionId]=[t1].[SubdivisionId]
Inner Join [PTCDbTracker].[dbo].[Status] as [t2] on [t1].[StatusId]=[t2].[StatusId]
Inner Join [PTCDbTracker].[dbo].[ConnectingSubs] as [t3] on [t0].[SubdivisionId]=[t3].[SubdivisionId] 
Inner Join [PTCDbTracker].[dbo].[Subdivision] as [t4] on ([t2].[StatusId]=[t4].[StatusId] AND [t3].[ConnectingSubId]=[t4].[SubdivisionId])
Inner Join [PtcDbTracker].[dbo].[TrackDatabase] as [t5] on t3.ConnectingSubId = t5.SubdivisionId

Where [t0].[SubdivisionId] = '90'
AND [t5].[Version] BETWEEN 8000 AND 9000

Group By t1.Name, t2.Description, t4.Name, t2.Description, t5.ActualPublicationEndDate
```

Which returns:

```
Subdivision     SubStatus    ConnectingSubName  ConnectingSubStatus       ActualPublicationEndDate      Version
San Bernardino  In Editing   Alameda Corridor   In Editing                2013-12-17 00:00:00.0000000   8000
San Bernardino  In Editing   Harbor             In Editing                2014-04-25 00:00:00.0000000   8001
San Bernardino  In Editing   Alameda Corridor   In Editing                2014-05-01 00:00:00.0000000   8001
San Bernardino  In Editing   Alameda Corridor   In Editing                2014-09-25 00:00:00.0000000   8002
```

What I really want to return are Lines 2 and 4. I know that the Group By clause is creating groups of 1, but if I try to take anything out I get an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using MS Sql SMS 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `row_number()`.  Something like this:

```
with t as (
      Select [t1].[Name] AS Subdivision, [t2].[Description] AS SubStatus,
             [t4].[Name] AS ConnectingSubName, [t2].[Description] As ConnectingSubStatus,
             [t5].[ActualPublicationEndDate], [t5].[version] as Version
      From [PtcDbTracker].[dbo].[TrackDatabase] [t0] INNER Join
           [PTCDbTracker].[dbo].[Subdivision] [t1]
           on [t0].[SubdivisionId] = [t1].[SubdivisionId] Inner Join
           [PTCDbTracker].[dbo].[Status] [t2]
           on [t1].[StatusId]=[t2].[StatusId] Inner Join
           [PTCDbTracker].[dbo].[ConnectingSubs] [t3]
           on [t0].[SubdivisionId]=[t3].[SubdivisionId] Inner Join
           [PTCDbTracker].[dbo].[Subdivision] [t4]
           on ([t2].[StatusId]=[t4].[StatusId] AND [t3].[ConnectingSubId]=[t4].[SubdivisionId]) Inner Join
          [PtcDbTracker].[dbo].[TrackDatabase] [t5]
           on t3.ConnectingSubId = t5.SubdivisionId
      Where [t0].[SubdivisionId] = '90' AND [t5].[Version] BETWEEN 8000 AND 9000
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Subdivision, SubStatus,   ConnectingSubName
                                order by version desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

This uses `row_number()` to get the row with the largest version for each entity, and then returns that row.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly, I am going to have to look a lot more into how to use the row number function more in some of my queries

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your query is `ActualPublicationEndDate` column in `group by` you need to remove it from `group by` and `select` list

Instead you can use `Row_Number` to find the max `version` per `Subdivision, SubStatus, ConnectingSubName and ConnectingSubStatus`.

```
Select *
from 
(
select *,
       row_number() over(partition by Subdivision, SubStatus, ConnectingSubName, ConnectingSubStatus 
                          order by [t5].[version] desc) RN
From join..
..
) A
where RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're after the row from `TrackDatabase` with the highest version.  One approach is `row_number()`.  A simplified example:

```
select  *
from    T1
join    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by ConnectingSubId
                    order by version desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    T2
        ) as t2
on      t1.SubId = t2.ConnectingSubId
        and t2.rn = 1 -- Latest version only
```

The advantage of a `join` with a subquery is that you only have to partition by one column.